# Why doesn't it apply even if I modify launch_background.xml in android folder?

Tags: flutter

Why doesn't it apply even if I modify launch_background.xml?

Do I have to go through a different procedure after changing the settings?

Comment: is it showing in android studio preview screen ?

Comment: I modified the launch_background.xml of drawble-v21 and it was applied. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I modified the launch_background.xml of drawble-v21 and it was applied.

Answer (score 0):

You have to modify the launch_background.xml in drawable and in drawable-v21.